# How does ps get the executable of processes of other users?

Tags: linux, permissions, ps

When running as non-root, if I try to use [`readlink(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/readlink) on a `/proc/<pid>/exe` for a process not owned by me I get a permission error.  So how then does `ps` with the `-f` option, which isn't setuid root, determine the executables for processes of a different user?

Comment: How do you make `ps` show the running executable? The "usual" output I get is `/proc/<pid>/cmdline`, which is a world readable file ...

Comment: The `-f` option does it for me, like `ps -eaf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-f` option does not display the full path to the executable, it displays the command line used to invoke the executable. This information is world-readable, from `/proc/PID/cmdline`, unlike the path to the executable from `/proc/PID/exe` which can only be read by the user who executed the process.

You can check what data `ps` is reading by observing its system calls — run [`strace ps -ef -p 1 | less`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace):

```
…
stat("/proc/1", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
open("/proc/1/stat", O_RDONLY)          = 6
read(6, "1 (init) S 0 1 1 0 -1 4202752 78"..., 1024) = 191
read(6, "", 833)                        = 0
close(6)                                = 0
open("/proc/1/status", O_RDONLY)        = 6
read(6, "Name:\tinit\nState:\tS (sleeping)\nT"..., 1024) = 752
read(6, "", 272)                        = 0
close(6)                                = 0
…
open("/proc/1/cmdline", O_RDONLY)       = 6
read(6, "/sbin/init", 2047)             = 10
close(6)                                = 0
…
```

If you pass the `c` option, then `ps` reports the command name from `/proc/PID/stat`, which is also world-readable. This is the basename of the executable (with no path information) truncated to 16 characters.

I don't think `ps` has an option to report the path to the executable found in `/proc/PID/exe`. You can list it with `lsof` (the [`txt`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171565/why-is-the-code-section-called-a-text-section) file descriptor) — and it predictably complains `/proc/1/exe (readlink: Permission denied)` when asked to print the information about another user's process.

N.B. My answer is about Linux. The details of what information can be reported about other users' processes and how it works are very different across Unix variants.